# Toggle a td tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my problem. I have a table with 3 rows. Within each row there's a hidden 'check' icon tag that toggles on and off when you click a table's row. I've gotten that to work successfully so far. What i'm trying to do now is to only have one checkmark showing at a time. So if one row is already checked and you click on another row, it'll uncheck the previously checked row and show the checkmark in the newly selected row. Here's the HTML and js that I have currently.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr = $('#eventListings').find('tr');
    $(tr).click(function () {
        if ($(this).find('td i').hasClass('hide')) {
        $(this).find('td i').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $(this).find('td i').addClass('hide');
    }
    });
});
```

```html
 <table  id="events" class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>10/19 @ 4:30 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v San Francisco 49ers</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>10/23 @ 4:25 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v San Diego Chargers</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>11/23 @ 6:30 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v Miami Dolphins</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where is the element with `id` `eventListings`? Why haven't you included jquery in the snippert..? did you even check whether what you cliams to be working is working in it or not..?

Comment: On every click, hide ALL checkmarks, then show the clicked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the visible checked items using [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector) selector and then toggle the clicked item using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr = $('#events').find('tr');
    $(tr).click(function () {
        $("td i:visible").addClass('hide')
        $(this).find('td i').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
/*For Demo Purpose*/

i::after{
  content:"checked";
}
i.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table  id="events" class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>10/19 @ 4:30 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v San Francisco 49ers</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>10/23 @ 4:25 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v San Diego Chargers</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>11/23 @ 6:30 PM</td>
          <td>Denver Broncos v Miami Dolphins</td>
          <td><i class="icon-check hide"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```